# SQL Inner join two tables and extract a boolean value from second column based on condition

Tags: sql, inner-join, self-join

I have a table like below. Lets called it **Transactions**

```
id   scan_id   amount   date           description
1       123      10     2020-12-01      "tissue"
1       111      500    2020-12-01      "amount to mexico"
1       124      15     2020-12-01      "dairy product"
2       222      1000   2020-13-01      "amount to India"
2       154      10     2020-13-01      "dairy"
3       333      499    2020-14-01      "amt to philipines"
-
-
-
-
```

I want all transactions where scan_id in (111,222,333) along with a boolean value indicating whether a customer made any other transactions other than scan_id(111,222,333) on the same date.
Here scan_ids (111,222,333) refers to Money Tx and others are not.
Example required data as below

```
id   scan_id   amount   date           description            same_day_non_money_tx
1       111      500    2020-12-01      "amount to mexico"        Yes
2       222      1000   2020-13-01      "amount to India"         Yes
3       333      499    2020-14-01      "amt to philipines"       No
```

I thought of doing an inner join like below

```
select id, scan_id, amount, date, description
from transactions where scan_id in (111,222,333) as T1
inner join 
select id, scan_id, amount, date, description
from transactions where scan_id not in (111,222,333) as T2
on T1.id = T2.id
and T1.date = T2.date
```

but this gives me all the transactions which matches based on id and date. How do i get this matching as a separate column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions, if you want the details:

```
select t.*,
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when scan_id in (111, 222, 333) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id, date) as num_123,
             count(*) over (partition by id, date) as num
      from t
     ) t
where cnt <> num_123 and num_123 > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

using `inner join` and `group by` date with condition  `if count(*) > 1 then Yes`

```
select t1.*, case when count > 1 then 'Yes' else 'NO' end as same_day_non_money_tx from
(select * from my_table where scan_id in (111, 222, 333) ) t1
inner join 
(select count(*), date from my_table group by date) t2
on (t1.date = t2.date)
order by date;
```